# Is our site interested in advertising online EE courses?

Tags: discussion

I've been looking for a quality, free introductory Electrical Engineering online course for a while, and finally came across these two below, from [Coursera.org](http://coursera.org):

- [Fundaments of Electrical Engineering](http://www.coursera.org/course/eefun) (free)
- [Fundaments of Electrical Engineering - Laboratory](http://www.coursera.org/course/eefunlab) (free but requires ordering a lab kit costing around $250)

My questions:

**1. Does the EE.SE site have na interest in these courses?**

**2. If so, what is the proper/best way to advertise it to EE.SE users?**  I thought that someone could post a link to this question on the bulleting board and that would be it.

I think that this is an excelente opportunity for all of our new users who are avid to learn Electrical Engineering, but didn't have the chance of getting the fundamentals right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange does support advertising, but not through questions or answers.

You may refer to this link to the contact page: [How to advertise on Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact). There is an email address, namely ads@stackexchange.com specifically for this.

Answer (score 6):

While as clabacchio stated they shouldn't be supported through questions or answers I can't think of a reason that it couldn't be suggested as a [Community Promotion Ad](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/community-promotion-ads-2014). That would leave it up to the community to vote if they think it's worthwhile promoting or not.

Out of the top two at the moment (which are very useful and I upvoted both) EEVBlog contains some advertising (Amazon affiliate links for example) and of course OSHPark wants payment for their PCBs, so I don't think there's any requirement for everything to be totally free.

I've never nominated a site myself but you'd probably want to contact the company and check that it's OK with them and either get from them or design yourself a banner they approve of before going ahead to avoid any potential copyright / trademark issues.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think there's little reason to advertse or endorse a course until you've taken it yourself and found it valuable.  Coursera courses will not disappear if you miss one opportunity to take it.